# In Doctor Who, who has met himself/herself?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

I'm trying to think of which characters in "Doctor Who" have met themselves by virtue of time travel. So far I've got:

1. The Doctor (obviously) - multiple times.
2. The Master - John Simm's Master met Missy, played by Michelle Gomez, in the Twelfth Doctor story "The Doctor Falls".
3. The Brigadier - his self from 1983 met his self from 1977 briefly in the 1983 Fifth Doctor story "Mawdryn Undead".

Any others? Note that I'm looking for characters who meet their actual selves through time travel, not who meet a duplicate of themselves. Also, I'm only considering major/recurring characters.

Comment: Over the course of nearly 60 years, the answer is "a lot of people". Basically every companion has crossed their own timeline repeatedly

Comment: Crossing one's own timeline is not the same as meeting oneself in the flesh.

Comment: Does Amy Pond count in the Big Bang episode?

Comment: Rose meets herself in father’s day.

Comment: Why was this downvoted multiple times? Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: @LincolnMan: because people tend to dislike questions that ask for a list, because they're hard to answer completely.

Answer (score 8):

Off the top of my head, I can think of:

- **Jo Grant** was with The Doctor when their timelines crossed for a brief period in Death to the Daleks.
- The Doctor let **Rose** try not once but twice to save her father in Father's Day.
- **Amy and Rory** (and later just Amy) came to wave at themselves from a distance during the events of The Hungry Earth / Cold Blood.
- While **River Song** didn't actually meet herself, she appeared as the baby Melody Pond was abducted at the Battle of Demon's Run.
- **Rory Williams** met an aged version of himself in The Angels Take Manhattan. He also looked at his own grave later in the episode.

I expect there's quite a few more I can't pull back at the moment.

Comment: Amy Pond also met an older version of herself in "The Girl Who Waited"

Comment: @tilley31 And also a younger version The Big Bang

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of examples. I started writing an answer yesterday but it was just too many.

Comment: Clara Oswald also met herself in "Listen", watching herself walk away and saying "I look fine" or something like that.

Comment: Clara met many of herself in a Doctor Who short. Rose only saw herself at a distance and didn't interact when she tried to save her dad in "Father's Day" but she did hold her infant self in the same episode.

Answer (score 2):

The TARDIS crew saw themselves as exhibits in The Space Museum.

Turlough  had an [Out Of Body Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-body_experience), and saw himself from above in his first episode.

Mickey Smith met himself in another universe.

Amy and Rory see their future selves at a distance in The Hungry Earth. They wave.